# Is it possible to link an answer/comment from one post to another?

Tags: discussion, questions

If there are two posts with different problems but answer from one post can resolve the other one as well, can it be linked??
Just adding the link is not accepted as correct answer, in that case , just copy paste the answer from the other post??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, please don't copy it, that could be plagiarism. You need to *flag* the question, because it needs to be *closed* as the *duplicate* of the other question. You should usually flag the newer question of the two, unless that question and/or it answers are better.

Good programmers don't like to duplicate code in their projects (the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), so we don't duplicate Q&A content either.